Is there an exact expression for the full width half maximum of a sech^2 curve convolved on itself?
As some simple math can show, a Gaussian convolved onto itself is also a Gaussian. Importantly, the FWHM of the original gaussian compared to that of its convolved counterpart is different by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$
For a hyperbolic secant squared shaped function convolved onto itself, it is no longer a hyperbolic secant squared function, unlike the case mentioned above. If $\text{sech}^2(\frac{x}{b})$ is the function, it's convoled counterpart (with some scaling so thry both have a height of 1) is $3\text{csch}^2(\frac{x}{b})(\frac{x}{b}\text{coth}(\frac{x}{b})-1)$.
For $\text{sech}^2(\frac{x}{b})$, the FWHM is $b*\ln(3+\sqrt{8})$. However, I don't know the form for the FWHM of the convolved version. It's of the form $b*n$. This number $n$ is, extremely close, but not equal to $e$. It's $\approx$ 2.719... but I have no exact expression for it. Is $n$ truly transcendental? Is there a infinite series that which describes it? Or, is there an exact expression? All information on this is appreciated.
